# Python Proxies Returning Connection Error

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy

I've seen hundreds of posts with this same question but none of the answers ever work. I've tried doing everything on the post answers and they all don't work.

```py
import requests
import random

def get_proxies():
  request = requests.get('https://proxylist.geonode.com/api/proxy-list?limit=50&page=1&sort_by=lastChecked&sort_type=desc')
  request = request.json()['data']
  proxies = []
  for proxy in request:
    proxies.append(f'{proxy["ip"]}:{proxy["port"]}')
  return proxies

def format_proxy(proxy):
  return {'http': proxy, 'https': proxy}

if __name__ == '__main__':
  proxies = get_proxies()
  response =requests.get('https://api.ipify.org/', proxies=format_proxy(random.choice(proxies)), headers={"User-Agent": "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64; U; de) Presto/2.2.15 Version/10.00"})
  print(response.text)
```

I'm scraping the proxies from https://geonode.com/free-proxy-list/ and I keep getting the same error. I'm scraping new proxies every time I send a request so they shouldn't be invalid yet it's giving me a "max retry exceeded error"

```
  File "/home/runner/proxies/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 700, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/home/runner/proxies/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/runner/proxies/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 369, in connect
    self._tunnel()
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 901, in _tunnel
    (version, code, message) = response._read_status()
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 277, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/proxies/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/home/runner/proxies/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/runner/proxies/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ipify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    response =requests.get('https://api.ipify.org/', proxies=proxy, headers={"User-Agent": "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64; U; de) Presto/2.2.15 Version/10.00"})
  File "/home/runner/proxies/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/proxies/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/proxies/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/proxies/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 645, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/proxies/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 513, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ipify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')))
```

Comment: Could you add things that you already tried in order to avoid people answer you with the thing that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Using {'https': 'ip:port'. 'http': 'ip:port'} schema, using urllib proxies, using a function to refresh proxies.